# Polymer Routing - history management

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to implement routing using the following code :

```
HTML :

<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
route="{{route}}"
pattern="/etw/:page"
data="{{routeData}}"
tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<iron-pages
selected="[[page]]"
attr-for-selected="name"
fallback-selection="view404"
role="main">
      <my-view1 page="{{page}}" name="view1"></my-view1>
      <my-view2 page="{{page}}" name="view2"></my-view2>
      <my-view404 page="{{page}}" name="view404"></my-view404>
</iron-pages>
```

And the script is :

```
 static get observers() {
    return [
      '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
    ];
  }
 _routePageChanged(page) {
    // Polymer 2.0 will call with `undefined` on initialization.
    // Ignore until we are properly called with a string.
    /*if (page === undefined) {
      return;
    }*/

    // If no page was found in the route data, page will be an empty string.
    // Deault to 'view1' in that case.
    this.page = page || 'home';
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    // Close a non-persistent drawer when the page & route are changed.
    /*if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
      this.$.drawer.close();
    }*/
 }

 _pageChanged(page) {
    // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
    var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
    Polymer.importHref(
        resolvedPageUrl,
        null,
        this._showPage404.bind(this),
        true);
 }
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to visit second view (view2) and then use browser back button. Only the URL on the screen changes but not the view. I looked into it and found that _routePageChanged(page) method is not getting called. any ideas?

One weird observation, I am experiencing the issue on a remote server running Apache 2.4.23, but not on Apache 2.4.18 or Nginx running on my localhost. I am not sure if this information is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of observing the property `page`, you can observe `path` instead. e.g. by changing

```
'_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
```

to

```
'_routePageChanged(routeData.path)',
```

Then, you can check the value of `routeData.page`, and take action.

Ref. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/routing#take-action-on-route-changes